# how to find number of open files in linux for a specific time range?

Tags: linux, cassandra-2.0

we have had cassandra instance crashes due to too many open files error.
in /etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf, nofile was set to 1M (now I increased it to 5M). lsof | wc -l reported about 46K open files (post crash).

Is there a way to find out what was the # open files at the time of crash?

Thanks,